# Angular 2 http many subscribers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I have a Page and a Service in Angular 2.

When i call the service function `this.Auth.login()`, it makes a http post request. My problem is, that as soon as the request returns data, i want to work with that data in the service AND the page.

I tried all kinds of stuff, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

I know that my code can't work like this because right now `this.Auth.login()` return a subscriber object. If i remove the '.subscribe()' in the service, it works in the Page. But thats not what i need.

I also tried to return a promise, but couldn't make it work either.

Does anybody know how i can achieve to have the data from the `http.post` in both controllers and work with it as soon as the request is finished?

---

Here's my code

Page:

```
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/signin/signin.html'
})
export class Signin {

    constructor(app: IonicApp, auth: AuthService){
        this.Auth = auth;
    }

    signIn = function() {
        this.Auth.login(this.user.email, this.user.password)
            .subscribe(data => {do some stuff here});
         // maybe a promise with .then can solve this
    };
}
```

Service:

```
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private http;

    constructor(http:Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    login(email, password) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // maybe i need to return this as a promise
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/auth/local', JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                }), {
                    headers: headers
                })
                .subscribe(data => {
                    do some stuff here too with the data
                ));
                // i tried to add .toPromise() but that didn't work
    }
}
```

I left out the other lines of code so there might be some dependencies missing. It's all good though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` in the body of the `Service` `login`. i.e

```
.map(data => {
                do some stuff here too with the data
                // still bubble up
                return data;
            ));
```

Comment: I tried that and i get the error `this.http.post(...).map is not a function`.

Comment: add  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';  in AuthService

Comment: Is it correct to say that the `map` callback won't be executed unless something else calls `subscribe()` (the service shown, in this case)? If so, that is something to be aware of, if you are relying on doing something with the data regardless of whether the calling code calls `subscribe()` on the observable.

Comment: ok `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` worked, but the code in map doesn't seem to be executed even though `subscribe()` is called in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i don't know if this is legit but it seems to work for me:

```
var res = this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/auth/local', JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }), {
        headers: headers
    });

res.subscribe(
    data => {
        console.log('data');
    },
    err => {
        console.log('err');
    },
    () => {  
        console.log('next');
    }
);

return res;
```

Comment: `.map()` should work (i.e., @basarat's answer).  Here's a working plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/vVL2oskhgH781PUz4yd6?p=preview